# If an enemy hits a duplicate from the Mirror Image spell, does it trigger the Tempest cleric's Wrath of the Storm feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, reactions

I'm playing D&D 5th edition. My character is a multiclassed Tempest cleric level 2/Sorcerer level 9.

If an enemy hits one of the duplicates from a *Mirror Image* spell cast by me, does it trigger the Tempest cleric's Wrath of the Storm feature?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *You* are not hit when an attack hits a duplicate from *mirror image*, so Wrath of the Storm does not activate

The [Tempest cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#TempestDomain)'s [Wrath of the Storm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#WrathoftheStorm-149) feature description states (PHB, p. 62; emphasis mine):

> [...] When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see **hits you with an attack**, you can use your reaction to cause the creature to make a Dexterity saving throw. [...]

Meanwhile, the *[mirror image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mirror-image)* spell states, in part (emphasis mine):

> Each time a creature targets you with an attack during the spell's duration, roll a d20 to determine whether the attack **instead targets one of your duplicates**.
>
> [...]
>
> A duplicate's AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier. If an attack **hits a duplicate**, the duplicate is destroyed. A duplicate can be destroyed only by an attack that hits it. [...]

When a duplicate is hit by an attack, *you* are not hit by that same attack; because of this, you cannot activate Wrath of the Storm.